# Storing battles and battle logs in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating an online RPG where players can battle each other and I want to be able to display each "battle action" in a structured manner after the battle.

My initial though was to have a Battle table, a Battlelog that belongs to a battle and has many "Actions" through another table. My idea was to have each record in the Actions table have a number (at which point the action occured in the battle), a battlelog id and then a string that says something like "Player 1 attacked Player 2 for 5 damage".

Are there any obvious problems with this approach? Will it be a problem if I have 1000s of battle that each have 100-500 actions? if so, got an idea to a better solution? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No problem with this approach.
Just keep in mind to create propper indexes to access the actions fast.

Comment: Would it be better to just concatenate each action into a long string, and store it in the battlelog table instead?

Comment: depends on what you want the actions for. If you allways access *all* actions of a battle, storing them in a single column would be faster. Then you could use `serialize` to store the Array of (point,test) hashes, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html